# What does "y ~ 1" and "data[1:14] means?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution

```
modbinull <- glm(ybin ~ 1, femsmoke[1:14,],family=binomial)
```

1. I'm new to R and I'm learning loglinear models. The goal is to see how this null model from binomial GLM is the same as the two-way interaction model from Poisson GLM.

```
modj <- glm(y ~ smoker*age + dead, femsmoke,family=poisson)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When someone does `~ 1`, it just means they are regressing on nothing but the intercept. So there is just an intercept (e.g., the mean, or the overall probability in the sample—the naive expected value). That is what they mean by "null model."

For more context: This comes from writing regression in Greek notation, where you multiply the $X$ matrix by the $\beta$ matrix. And since everyone has the same intercept (the first column of $\beta$), everyone has a value of 1 for the first column in $X$.

Whereas in the second model, they are regressing on `dead`, `smoker`, `age`, and the interaction between `smoker` and `age` (using `*` fills in the main effects for you).

As for `data[1:14, ]`, that is more of a question for Stack Overflow (so I'm voting to move it there), but it's basically saying just take the first 14 rows. R indexes in square brackets by saying `columns, rows`. And if you leave either blank, it just takes all of them. So that is saying "give me the first fourteen rows, and all the columns."